# SkiaSharp keeps installing in Xamarin.Droid project but installation does not get complete. It just keeps installing.?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, telerik, nuget-package, skiasharp

I have a xamarin.Forms App in VS for Mac in which I am using a Telerik UI control. When i build my .Droid project, it gives me an exception : **FileNotFoundException -> SkiaSharp 1.59.0 is missing perhaps it is not installed for mono for android.**

I am trying to install SkiaSharp from Nuget but it just keeps installing but never gets completed. I waited for 10 minutes but did not happen and it just kept installing it. 
Any solutions please? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have try to install the `SkiaSharp` from nuget package in Mac and there is no problem. When you install other nuget package is the same problem? If it did, maybe your VS network configuration has some problem, so it cannot download this package. You could restart your VS and Mac and try again.

As an alternative choice, you could directly download the nuget package from this [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp/), then you could local feed this nuget package to your project reference.